# Subtracting this Rational Expression (using LCD)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, rational-functions

*My textbook mentioned a number of rules I should use when subtracting rational expressions, and they include:*

1) When the denominators are **different**, you can **write equivalent fractions with the same denominator** (but it's easier to use **LCD**)

2) When the denominators are the **same**, all you need to do is **add/subtract the numerators** and **write the answer as a rational expression over the common denominator**

Using these rules, I applied them to simplify this expression: $\frac{1}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$ - $\frac{4}{(x + 1)}$

Here's what I did:

$\frac{1}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$ - $\frac{4 (x - 3)}{(x + 1)(x - 3)}$ (I multiplied by LCD)

$\frac{1 - 4x - 12}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$ (I did this since denominators are the same; in the numerator, I expanded $4 (x - 3)$)

$\frac{- 4x - 11}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$ (My final answer)

However, in my textbook, they got: $\frac{- 4x + 13}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$

I don't understand how they got this? I'm thinking that the method I used might've been wrong or I am making some mistake.

Please help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$1-4(x-3)=1-4x-4(-3)=1-4x+12=13-4x$$

Answer (score 1):

Watch your brackets: $1 - 4(x-3) = 1 - (4x-12) = 1 - 4x + 12 = 13- 4x$, as $-(-12) =12$.

Answer (score 1):

You will get $$\frac{1-4(x-3)}{(x-3)(x+1)}=\frac{1-4x+12}{(x-3)(x+1)}$$ with $$x\ne 3$$ and $$x\ne -1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1 - 4x - 12}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$$

Should have been  $$\frac{1 - 4x + 12}{(x - 3)(x + 1)}$$

The negative in front of the fraction distribute to all the terms of the numerator, not just the first term.